# Does 鴉靉魅 work for the name Aimi?

Tags: kanji, names

I tried to find kanji for the name Aimi by looking at the readings of kanji on jisho.org.

Do the kanji 鴉靉魅 work for the name Aimi?

Comment: How did you come up with these kanji?

Comment: Searching for their readings on jisho.org :)

Comment: It works except that almost no native speaker can even guess the reading...

Answer (score 2):

Well, it sort of works, depending how you interpret "works".

The ENAMDICT database contains many rare names (and [over 100 ways](https://jisho.org/search/aimi%20%23names) of writing the name あいみ in *kanji* — but not 鴉靉魅).

The database *does* contain entries

- あいか 【鴉嘩】
- そうあ 【蒼鴉】
- えいこ 【靉子】

as well as several names using 魅 for the (common) ending, such as

- あさみ 【亜佐魅】

as "female given name" suggesting that all characters might be used in a name.

Reading 鴉 and 靉 as *a* and *i* is "theoretically" possible, but almost impossible to guess. Note also that these two are *hyōgai* *kanji*, so they could not be used in a given name for a baby girl (or boy) born in Japan now.

Also, the choice of *kanji* does looks a bit like someone wanted a name with as many *kanji* and as many strokes as possible.

If you wanted a more "realistic" name you could keep 魅 as *mi* and put either

1. two *kanji* for *ai*, such as 安意 for 安意魅, say, or
2. a single *kanji* for *ai*, such as 愛 or 和 or 想 or 藍 for 愛魅 etc.

I think this way you can get a pretty name, which isn't too eccentric.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :D

Comment: 愛魅 looks really lovely.

Comment: 「魅」って・・あんまり良い感じしないですよね、モノノケみたいな意味もあるし。。フツーに愛美、愛海、愛実、藍美とか亜衣美あたりにしとかはったら…って思ってしまう。。。

Comment: 愛美 can also work I think...  oh @Chocolate already mentioned it :))